# Changing colors of connector shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to connect rectangle shapes via connectors in MS Excel via VBA which works fine:

```
Sub ACT_PTRN()
Call Data_Model
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Model Overview").Shapes
        'connect Actuarial Portfolio with Pattern
        Set shpCON = .AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 10, 10, 50, 50)
        shpCON.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect shpACTPF, 4
        shpCON.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect shpPTRN, 2
            With shpCON
                .Line.Weight = 2.5
                .Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 50
            End With
            End With
End Sub
```

I have several of those connections between different shapes. Now my question, I would like to grey the past connector lines before adding the next connector lines. I need some kind of select code only for the connector shapes without all the other shape types and to change their colors.

Best Regards,
Saied